# pvp.net kernel has stopped working cannot install league of legends

Tags: league-of-legends

After a long protest of the death of Ahri's splash art, I have decided to try modding it again. But upon clicking the league icon I got "pvp.net kernel has stopped working" I deleted league from my computer to try and reinstall it. That made it worse. I cant even run the set up, it has the same error. I tried running it as admin but it only gives me the option to remove it.

Comment: Are there any error logs? Could you provide them for us?

Comment: How did you "delete league"? If you didn't run the uninstaller, there are likely remnants on your machine such as in the registry or appdata folders. Try choosing the option to remove and then attempt the install again.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are on windows use programs and features to uninstall LOL (If it still shows up in the list)
2. Use a tool like [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) to clean your registry, make sure to back up your registry when it asks if you want to do so.
3. Reinstall league with an install directly from their website.
4. Let all patches run and the client fully update

> I have decided to try modding it again.

Did you make any changes or mod anything before this issue arose? If so these details can help to fix the issue if the above steps do not work.